# Split a delimited column but keep rows

Tags: python, dataframe

I have over 100 columns and 1000 rows.  Some columns have duplicate pipe delimiters on consecutive rows. I'd like to separate it to a single string for each row.

Original Dataframe

```
**Cars  Color   Customization   Type**
Buick   yellow  radio   Car
Chevy   gray|brown|blue radio | exhaust truck
Chevy   gray|brown|blue radio | exhaust truck
Chevy   gray|brown|blue radio | exhaust truck
Mercedes    red|blue    seats| carpets  car
Mercedes    red|blue    seats| carpets  car
```

```
 df = pd.DataFrame ({'Cars': ['Buick', 'Chevy', 'Chevy', 'Chevy', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes'], 
'Color': ['yellow', 'gray|brown|blue', 'gray|brown|blue', 'gray|brown|blue', 'red|blue', 'red|blue'],
 'Customization': ['radio', 'radio|exhaust', 'radio|exhaust', 'radio|exhaust', 'seats|carpets', 'seats|carpets'],
 'Type': ['car', 'truck', 'truck', 'truck', 'car', 'car']})
```

This how I'd like it to look

```
**Cars  Color   Customization   Type**
Buick   yellow  radio   Car
Chevy   gray    radio   truck
Chevy   brown   exhaust truck
Chevy   blue        truck
Mercedes    red seats   car
Mercedes    blue    carpets car
```

So far I used: df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split('|'), axis = 1) to create lists of the piped columns. Using explode() creates new rows which is not what I want it to do.

Comment: One problem I see is how to save rows that have more than one delimiter? in your example a Chevy can be brown and have a radio. This I don't see in your expected outcome. Do you want all possible combinations as a unique row?

Comment: No it doesn't need to have each of the combinations in a single row.  As long as one of the attributes is connected to the Chevy, it's fine.

Comment: please post the data as a  code or text, and not image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

s = """Cars Color   Customization   Type
Buick   yellow  radio   Car
Chevy   gray|brown|blue radio|exhaust   truck
Chevy   gray|brown|blue radio|exhaust   truck
Chevy   gray|brown|blue radio|exhaust   truck
Mercedes    red|blue    seats|carpets   car
Mercedes    red|blue    seats|carpets   car
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), delimiter='\t').drop_duplicates()

out = (df.set_index('Cars').apply(lambda x: x.str.split('|'))
              .apply(lambda x: x.apply(pd.Series).stack())
              .reset_index()
              .drop(columns=['level_1'])
       )
```

##### `>>> display(out)`

[image]

Comment: Gives me a KeyError: "None of ['Cars'] are in the columns".  So to check I tried df.columns which gives me : (['Cars Color   Customization   Type'],.  So I changed the column name to "Cars" but got different errors.

Comment: It means that the format of your actual data doesn't match the one you described in your question. `1)` how do you read your dataframe ? `2)` what are the errors you got and in which line they occured ?

Comment: a better representation  of my dataframe:

Comment: ` df = pd.DataFrame ({'Cars': ['Buick', 'Chevy', 'Chevy', 'Chevy', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes'], 'Color': ['yellow', 'gray|brown|blue', 'gray|brown|blue', 'gray|brown|blue', 'red|blue', 'red|blue'], 'Customization': ['radio', 'radio|exhaust', 'radio|exhaust', 'radio|exhaust', 'seats|carpets', 'seats|carpets'], 'Type: ['car', 'truck', 'truck', 'truck', 'car', 'car']})`